# tslint: Forbidden http url in string

Tags: typescript, tslint, node-fetch

```
function getStuff(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction): void {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/stuff')
        .then((data: {}) => {
            res.send(data.body._readableState.buffer.head.data.toString());
        })
        .catch((err: {}) => {
            res.json(err);
        });
}
```

The error I'm getting is `[tslint] Forbidden http url in string 'http://localhost:3000/stuff' (no-http-string)`

I could get this error ignored by putting `// tslint:disable-next-line` above the `fetch()` method, but is there any other solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Description of this rule is `Do not use strings that start with 'http:'. URL strings should start with 'https:'.`

1) Put `// tslint:disable-next-line:no-http-string` above the `fetch()` method to disable inspection for one line

2) Put

```
{
    "rules": {
        "no-http-string": false, // <---- this line
    }
}
```

in `tslint.json` to disable inspection for all project